# Converting a string to a list with numbers consisting of several characters

Tags: dart

I'm studying Dart and I don't have enough practical examples to understand some of the topics.

So there is a task to turn a string into a list, so that numbers consisting of several characters become one element of the list. Example:

`String a = '65bf+(100.46+22)/hf2-1'` => `List<String> arr ['65', 'b', 'f', '+', '(', '100.46', '+', '22', ')', '/', 'd', 'h', 'f', '2', '-', '1']`

The length of the string can be any. Numbers in a string can be either integers or decimals.

It seems to me that here you can turn a string into a necessary list by generating a new list using a regular expression. However, attempts to do something working were not successful.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in dartpad:

```
import 'dart:convert'; // for json
void main() {
  String a = '65bf+(100.46+22)/hf2-1';
  var matcher = RegExp(r'([0-9.]+|.)');
  var matches = matcher.allMatches(a).map((e) => e.group(0));

  print(matches);
  print(json.encode(matches.toList()));
}
```

Output is:

```
(65, b, f, +, (, 100.46, +, 22, ), /, h, f, 2, -, 1)
["65","b","f","+","(","100.46","+","22",")","/","h","f","2","-","1"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: My decades of experience with Perl seems to have paid off. :)